# VBA - Create Array from Named Range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am ultimately trying to export certain sheets in my excel workbook as pdf's.

I have all the names of the sheets I want to export in a named range (in a column). As an example I have "Total" in A1 and "Total (P)" in A2 on the "Data_Mappings" tab. And these two cells have a named range of "Incurred_Graphs".

Here is my current code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim TabsArray() As Variant

fp = "C:\Users\chris\Documents\Testing\Graphs\Graphs.pdf"
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook


TabsArray = Worksheets("Data_Mappings").Range("Incurred_Graphs")

'TabsArray = Array("Total", "Total (P)")

wb.Sheets(TabsArray).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=fp, _
    Quality:=x1QualityStandad, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

I get a type mismatch on the "TabsArray =" line.

If I change the tabs array to commented out line, everything will work, and I will get my pdf of those 2 tabs.

I eventually would like to pick the named range to use in the array based on a single cell from another sheet. Where the user has a dropdown and can pick for example, "Incurred Graphs" or "Paid Graphs". But I want to get this first part down without having to hardcode in all the names of the sheets into VBA.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified code that works exactly how I needed it too.

```
Sub pdf()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim TabsArray() As Variant
Dim TabsArrayRng As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
fp = "C:\Users\chris\Documents\Testing\Graphs\" & Sheets("Export to PDF").Range("D7").Text & ".pdf"

Set TabsArrayRng = Sheets("Data_Mappings").Range("Incurred_Graphs")

N = TabsArrayRng.Rows.Count
ReDim TabsArray(1 To N)
For i = 1 To N
    TabsArray(i) = TabsArrayRng.Cells(i, 1).Value2
Next i

wb.Sheets(TabsArray).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=fp, _
    Quality:=x1QualityStandad, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False


End Sub
```

I couldn't directly set the range to the array but needed to use a for/next loop to place each part of the array in.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim TabsArray() As Variant

fp = "C:\Users\chris\Documents\Testing\Graphs\Graphs.pdf"
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

wb.Sheets("Data_Mappings").Range("Incurred_Graphs").Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=fp, _
    Quality:=x1QualityStandad, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Now I'm not sure if you want to export selection or the whole sheet. If only selections you would change the ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat with Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat

Comment: Gave me a run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed. (I also have a selected print range set on each tab so I can just print each sheet)

Comment: Strange. What if you try wb.Sheets("Data_Mappings").Select and then ActiveSheet.Range("Incurred_Graphs").Select. On which line does it fail them?

Answer (score 0):

You should first activate the **Data_Mappings** sheet First. Then select the range .U cant directly select the range from another sheet.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim TabsArray() As Variant

fp = "C:\Users\chris\Documents\Testing\Graphs\Graphs.pdf"
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
wb.Sheets("Data_Mappings").select
Range("Incurred_Graphs").Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=fp, _
    Quality:=x1QualityStandad, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Comment: This will just pdf the "Data_Mappings" sheet. I am looking to use the range from "Data_Mappings" to export each tab labeled in this range.